# How to get Coco/R parser to not be greedy

Tags: parsing, lexical-analysis, parser-generator, cocor

My ATG file defines a code block as

```
Codeblock = "<#" {anychar} "#>"
```

When the Coco generated parser comes across a block like this:

```
<#
   a=5;
   print "Hello world!";
#>
```

The token picks up

```
a=5;
print "Hello
```

This is exactly what I want.

However, when it comes across code like this:

```
<#
   a=5;
   print "Hello World";
#>
<#
   b=5;
   print "Foo Bar";
#>
```

The token, greedily picks up

```
 a=5;
 print "Hello World";
 #>
 <#
   b=5;
   print "Foo Bar";
```

How can I let Coco/R know not to do this?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
codeblock = "<#" {anychar} "#>" .
anychar = (expression|procedure) ";" .
```

by making anychar ended with ";" then cocor cannot mistakenly parse anychar with this pattern "#> <#"

Comment: I already have anychar defined as `anychar = ANY.` so that includes the semi-colon. Also, since the semi-colon is used as endline, I cannot exclude it from anychar.

Comment: `ANY` is too much. use `"qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM"` instead.

Comment: `anychar = (expression|procedure) ";" EOL .` where 'EOL = CHR(10) .' in CHARACTERS section

Answer (score 0):

Your terminals need to be more explicit.

"ANY" introduces ambiguity which is why the `#><#` is being parsed, your codeblock will treat everything between the FIRST `<# and LAST #>` as being part of the set "ANY" since that is how your grammar has defined a codeblock.

Perhaps try:

```
code = codeblock {codeblock} EOF
codeblock = "<#" {anychar} "#>"
```